# Update таблицы в MS Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, c#, sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте! Я создал в базу данных и таблицу в ней Post в SQL SERVER 2008.

```
Post(PostID (uniqueidentifier), PostBody(text), PostCommentCount(int))
```

Есть процедура Post_UpdateCommentCount:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Post_UpdateCommentCount
    @PostID Uniqueidentifier    
AS
    UPDATE Post SET PostCommentCount = PostCommentCount + 1 
    WHERE PostID = @PostID
    RETURN
```

Но запись не обновляется.

```
USE [BlogDatabase]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Post_UpdateCommentCount]
        @PostID = 6ba306e4-6245-46d5-93cc-7256e127b6bf

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Выходит следующая ошибка:

> `Incorrect syntax near 'ba306e4'.`

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте в  одинарные ковычки заключить значение.